# json API data to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, api

I'm trying to put data retrieved via an API into a pandas dataframe. I managed to get the data but I'm having issues in converting json into a pandas dataframe. This is the code that I have now:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=1200')

data = r.text

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I tried to generate a dataframe but I get the error:

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `r.json()` instead `r.text`:

```
data = r.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['results'])
print(df)

# Output
                            name                                       url
0                      bulbasaur      https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/
1                        ivysaur      https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/
2                       venusaur      https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/
3                     charmander      https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/
4                     charmeleon      https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5/
...                          ...                                       ...
1121             copperajah-gmax  https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10224/
1122              duraludon-gmax  https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10225/
1123  urshifu-single-strike-gmax  https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10226/
1124   urshifu-rapid-strike-gmax  https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10227/
1125     toxtricity-low-key-gmax  https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10228/

[1126 rows x 2 columns]
```